# Raspberry Pi Firmware - user updateable - which bits live on sd and which on the hardware

Tags: hardware, firmware

I'm trying to understand the firmware on the Raspberry Pi.

My understanding was that *firmware* related only to persistent software not influenced by anything which is on any particular SD card, but it seems that's not the case on the pi and that *firmware* is also being used to describe low level boot states that are loaded from the SD card.

I would like to know are there any user upgradable firmware settings that do persist without reference to any particular SD cards contents? If so, which ones (in general terms)?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware there is no user upgradeable memory or firmware within the Pi.  There are a few bits of One-Time Programmable (OTP) memory once used to record usage which invalidated the warranty.

All state is held within the SD card.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer, I really was hoping for a different one but think I suspected as much. I can't make sense of a problem that I was having - the wireless network interface seemed not to exist on a Pi0W until I updated the SD card on another Pi and inserted it back into the 0W, when all was fine. I then re-imaged the card from the same .img file and expected the same problem to recur - it didnt. It seems the original problem (no wifi adaptor) and solution has occurred a few times and the Pi is working fine but why the problem didn't come back on the 2nd pass is an itch for me. More

Comment: The Pi3 also uses OTP to control boot mode.

Comment: @Milliways I didn't know that.  What does it do?  Control net boot or similar?

Comment: @joan I haven't actually tried this myself (having no desire to netboot or boot from USB)  but this came out of reading https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/pi-3-booting-part-i-usb-mass-storage-boot/ and some of the following links which include "The flow of boot begins with reading the OTP to decide on the valid boot modes enabled."

Comment: @Milliways Like you I have no desire to net or USB boot so am not familiar with the procedure.  I suppose some reading is in order.

Comment: @nicksoph: The reason the wlan interface was "nonexistent" was probably nothing to do with the hardware but simply related to your software configuration. If this sort of thing occurs again, post a question that tells us exactly how you determined that the network interface "seemed not to exist" (`ip addr` didn't show it? Not probed in the boot logs?) and we can work out the details of what was going wrong.